# Java String.split() with a regex

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing, split

I have a parsing question. 
I have sentences that are stored as Strings. I want to grab each word in each sentence however I would like to filter which words I grab. For example say I have a sentence like the following:

> Hell0 3v3ryb0dy @ stackoverflow $people \implies queen$ equals ~queen --> ~people.
>   /#logic

I would do the following:

1. grab 'H3ll0'
2. grab 3v3ryb0dy
3. throw away the @
4. grab 'people' from '$people'
5. grab 'implies' from '\implies'
6. grab 'queen' from 'queen$'
7. grab 'equals'
8. grab 'queen' from '~queen'
9. throw away -->
10. grab 'people' from '~people'
11. grab 'logic' from '/#logic'

Essentially I want only alphanumeric characters and whenever I have some other character such as a \ before or after a word I want to disregard this other character.

Currently I am doing:`sentence.split(" ")`

This gets the individual words from the sentence but it grabs '$people' and '~people' and treats them differently when I want them to be treated the same.

1. How can I achieve this?
2. Would a regex help me here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split the string with this regex `\\W+`, split at one or more non-word character(s).

```
String sentence = "Hell0 3v3ryb0dy @ stackoverflow $people \\implies queen$ equals ~queen --> ~people. /#logic";
String[] split = sentence.split("\\W+");
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(split));
```

**Output**

> [Hell0, 3v3ryb0dy, stackoverflow, people, implies, queen, equals, queen, people, logic]

Answer (score 1):

I am using this regex.
`[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+` (Edited)
and the output I get is:
`Hell0 3v3ryb0dy stackoverflow people implies queen equals queen people logic`

Is this what you are expecting?

Snipped from [myregextester](http://myregextester.com/index.php)

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
class Module1{
  public static void main(String[] asd){
  String sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
  Pattern re = Pattern.compile("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
  Matcher m = re.matcher(sourcestring);
  String result = m.replaceAll("");
  }
}

$sourcestring after replacement:
Hell0 3v3ryb0dy stackoverflow people implies queen equals queen people logic
```

Comment: I stil want to split my sentence by spaces. So say I do the following: `wordsInSentence = sentence.split(" ");` I would like this code to also filter out non-word characters with the functionality in my question

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus: Did you try my answer?

Comment: -1. With this I got this output: `[, H, e, l, l, 0,  , 3, v, 3, r, y, b, 0, d, y,  , ,  , s, t, a, c, k, o, v, e, r, f, l, o, w,  , , p, e, o, p, l, e,  , , i, m, p, l, i, e, s,  , q, u, e, e, n, ,  , e, q, u, a, l, s,  , , q, u, e, e, n,  , ,  , , p, e, o, p, l, e, ,  , , l, o, g, i, c]`.

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus Why don't you try the regex `[^A-Za-z0-9]*` on each split word?

Comment: Obviously you need to use replace with the regex.

Comment: @BheshGurung, you need to use this regex and replace it with "" (Empty String). You have split on the regex which is resulting in what you've posted.

Comment: @Srinivas: But what the OP is try to do is `String.split(regex)`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19063/discussion-between-srinivas-and-bhesh-gurung)

Comment: You can actually use a one-liner `replaceAll`. No need to go through Pattern and Matcher.

Comment: That was snipped from regextester which I used to test the regex. Mentioned that as well in the answer. Yes `replaceAll` is what I would have gone with.

Comment: You need to change the `*` to `+`: `[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+`.  Your regex can match nothing, meaning it will match at every character boundary regardless of what follows it.  If it happens to see any of the unwanted characters it will consume them, but something or nothing, it will always match.  The regex in your comment  (`[^A-Za-z0-9]*`) has the same problem.  It won't throw an exception or return incorrect results, but it's doing lot of work it doesn't need to do.